# What weapons are class restricted?

Tags: diablo-iii

[This page](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/#filter=wizard) suggests that the wizard can use:

- Axes
- Daggers
- Maces
- Spears
- Swords

(Click on the Wizard icon, and all of those weapons are not disabled, meaning that the class can use them.)

[This Diablo Wiki article](http://www.diablowiki.net/Weapons) explains weapons types, but it is not clear whether the Wizard can use only wands, or other weapons.

So do you know the exact list or weapons type that a class can use? Or can you find this information somethere?

My motivation to know is that the damage per second of those weapons can change quite a bit from one to the other, and the spell damage is based on that. For example, the level 1 wand ([apprentice's want](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/apprentices-wand)) is only 3 DPS, whereas the level 1 spear ([javelin](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/javelin)) has a DPS of 7.2–8.4.

Comment: Does this count as speculation as the game hasn't yet come out (unless the title says: ... in Diabloe 3 beta)? Or am I horribly wrong again?

Comment: @JamesJiao yah not sure either, i know i asked one but decided that futher questions could wait till the game actually comes out and i get a chance to play it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any character (including wizards and witch doctors) can wield any non class-specific weapon, with a few small exceptions.

The [class-specific weapons](http://www.diablowiki.net/Class-Specific_Weapons) are:

- Ceremonial Knife (Witch Doctor)
- Hand Crossbow (Demon Hunter)
- Fist Weapon (Monk)
- Daibo (Monk)
- Mighty Weapon (Barbarian)
- Wand (Wizard)

There are also off-hand class-specific items, as well as class-specific armor.

In addition to the class weapons, a few classes are restricted from using certain general items. The restrictions are as follows:

- Wizard: No polearms or two-handed maces (other two-handed weapons are OK)
- Barbarian: No staves, no ranged
- Demon Hunter: No two-handed weapons other than bows and crossbows, some skills restricted to ranged weapons.
- Monk: No ranged
- Witch Doctor: No special restrictions

The idea behind having wands for Wizards is that the magic enchantments on them are particularly beneficial to the Wizard so it's more likely you'll be using a wand if you care about general Wizard stats or skills. You are otherwise, however, free to use whichever general weapon you want.

Comment: Not *quite* true. For instance, Monks can't use any ranged weapons, even the generic "bow" types, and Wizards can't use 2-handed weapons at all.

Comment: You mean two handed melee weapons, right? I can most definitely equip a bow on a wizard.

Comment: Yes. I meant 2-handed melee weapons. Blizzard's site refers to the three groups of items as "1-handed, 2-handed, and ranged".

Comment: @RavenDreamer I updated this with restrictions. Turns out that Wizards are mostly ok with two-handed weapons. Tested experimentally as well.

Comment: I think Witchdoctors aren't able to dual-wield, but I can't be sure.