# Are there any Barbarian specific items?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

I have been playing Diablo for the past week and have noticed something strange. I find items (Offhands, Weapons, exct...) that are class speficic and I am not allowed to equip them. (I'm sure they are all horrible for my class anyway.) However I am yet to find **anything** that is Barbarian specific. Are there any items just for me? It is becasue I am to Barbaric to operate unique technology?

Comment: I get a ton of those Barb belts

Comment: possible duplicate of [What weapons are class restrictive?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60442/what-weapons-are-class-restrictive)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each class in Diablo III has 3 kinds of items which are specific to them.

For the Barbarian, these are

- [Mighty Belts](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/mighty-belt/)
- [Mighty 1-Handed Weapons](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/mighty-weapon-1h/)
- [Mighty 2-Handed Weapons](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/mighty-weapon-2h/)

To get a more general overview you can go to [the items page on the official Diablo III site](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/) and look at all the item categories that are type-specific - as signified by the small class name next to them. You can also click the class in the top bar to see which item types that class can equip (both class-specific and general).

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

You can (as a Barbarian and **only** as Barbarian) equip Mighty Weapons and Mighty Belts. However there are two types of Mighty weapons, One-hand and Two-hand.

*There's even an achievement about this.*

[**Mighty Vengeance**](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/mighty-vengeance)

[image]

Comment: Here is a list with all unique-class-gear [Are class-specific weapons better than other weapon?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63828/are-class-specific-weapons-better-than-other-weapon)

Comment: You can even search for items with barb affixes, as long as you search for specific item (belt) that can have them. If you search "all armor", choice of barb affixes will not appear on drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

There are specific items for Barbarians too, I have found multiple myself. Barbarian specific items are called Mighty and exist as belts and various two-handed weapons (e.g. Mighty Belt and Mighty Axe). There is an achievement for wearing both a mighty belt and a mighty weapon at the same time.